# how to get the photos from a Facebook page using graph explorer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Well, I have a Facebook page. It has photos in it. I want the graph explorer to get the photos from it. I am able to get into the page and albums but not the photos. The response which given by the Graph explorer is `JSON`. I want that `JSON` to be used in my application.

Comment: Can you specify your server-side language? e.g. `PHP`

Comment: for now i am trying to get the JSON response from the graph explorer. I am using Objective C

Comment: Too bad, I don't know `Objective-C`, add that as a tag

Answer (score 0):

What part of

```
/{your_page_id}/photos/uploaded
```

is not working for you? See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/photos

Comment: this is what i got page-id?fields=photos.fields(images). This is what we get the photos which are on timeline.

Comment: You have to distinguish between all photos (also photos uploaded by other users and not the page itself, and only photos uploaded by the page). My answer is about the latter...

Comment: well in your case it juste says uploaded. It means every user who uploads can also be included it right?

Comment: Do you know how to parse the JSON using objective C?I got JSON for the required stuff.

Comment: Please read the docs I linked in my answer, and I already gave more detail in my comment.